# Searching inside an object in NeDB/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, nedb

First of all, I am using feathers client together with nedb and I followed this [documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/vanilla-rest.html).

So I have a json structured like this:

```
{
    personal: {
        name: 'Robert'
    }
},
{
    personal: {
        name: 'Mark'
    }
},
{
    personal: {
        name: 'Jester'
    }
}
```

And I want to search 'Robert'. My code for now looks like this:

```
users.find({ query: { personal: { name: 'Robert' } } }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

But I only get an empty array in my console `[]`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: try { 'personal.name': 'Robert' }

Comment: @Astro Syntax error

Comment: users.find({ query: { 'personal.name': 'Robert' } }).then ...  this one?

Comment: lol it worked haha @Astro

Comment: @Astro try to post it as answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mongo nested fields can be generally accessed using the . operator ([dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents))

Try this code:

> `users.find({ query: { 'personal.name': 'Robert' } }).then`